# Возможно ли поменять цвет инструментов разработчика в google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Существует ли возможность поменять цвет консоли в google chrome?
Чтобы как в FF, темное. Есть же для него темы оформления, но консоль и прочее не затрагиваю. Но возможно есть ещё что-то?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну вот, теперь хоть удаленно напоминает идеал. Жаль что самая лучшая тема (первая) не является рабочей, так как цвет строки выделяющий текст практически одинакового цвета с текстом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В *Chrome* применение пользовательских стилей к *Developer Tools* считается экспериментальным функционалом, поэтому для начала нужно:

1. Перейти по адресу `chrome://flags/` в браузере.
2. Найти опцию под названием `Enable Developer Tools experiments` и включить ее, если она была выключена.
3. Перезагрузить браузер.
4. Зайти в *Chrome Developer Tools*, перейти в настройки и на вкладке `Experiments` включить опцию `Allow custom UI themes`.

---

Начиная с 32 версии *Chrome*, способ, которым можно добавлять пользовательские стили для *Developer Tools*, изменился, теперь это можно сделать с помощью расширений. Вот некоторые ресурсы, на которых можно найти уже готовые темы:

- поискать в [Интернет-магазине Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/devtools%20theme?_category=extensions) расширения по ключевому слову `devtools theme`
- поискать на [github.com](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=devtools-theme) по ключевому слову `devtools theme`
- [Themes for Chrome Developer Tools](http://devthemez.com/themes/chrome-developer-tools)

---

Расширения не обязательно должны находиться в *Google Play*, их можно устанавливать из локальных папок. Для быстрого создания темы можно воспользоваться *Yeoman* генератором [generator-devtools-theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-devtools-theme), но можно сделать это и вручную следующим образом (инструкции для *Chrome 32+*, проверялся на Ubuntu 14.04):

1. Создать папку для своего расширения.
2. Файл `manifest.json`:

   ```
   {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "custom theme",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "devtools_page": "devtools.html"
   }
   ```
3. Файл `devtools.html`:

   ```
   <script src="devtools.js"></script>
   ```
4. Файл `devtools.js`:

   ```
   var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
   x.open('GET', 'style.css');
   x.onload = function() {
       chrome.devtools.panels.applyStyleSheet(x.responseText);
   };
   x.send();
   ```
5. Файл `style.css`:

   ```
   #-blink-dev-tools .tabbed-pane {
     background: red;
   }
   ```
6. Перейти по адресу `chrome://extensions/` в браузере.
7. Включить `Developer Mode`
8. Нажать на кнопку `Load unpacked extension...` и указать путь к только что созданной папке. Данное расширение должно появится в списке расширений.

Если после этого открыть *Chrome Developer Tools*, то часть панелей должна перекраситься в красный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советы для разработки пользовательских стилей:

- *Chrome Developer Tools* можно открыть в *Chrome Developer Tools*, так как это тоже HTML страница. Для этого нужно открыть *Chrome Developer Tools* в режиме отдельного окна, после чего нажать <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd>, что откроет новое окно с *Chrome Developer Tools* для первого окна. Теперь во втором окне можно пользоваться инспектором элементов и редактировать стили первого окна налету. Во вкладке `Network` первого окна можно посмотреть, какие ресурсы загружается страница, а именно CSS файлы со стандартными стилями, чтобы взять их за основу.
- После изменения содержимого `style.css` в своем расширении, для того, чтобы они вступили с силу, необходимо зайти на страницу `chrome://extensions/`, найти свое расширение и нажать кнопку `Reload` рядом с ним. После этого, заново открыв *Chrome Developer Tools*, стили должны обновиться.

---

Для версий Chrome до 32 порядок был следующим (способ не проверялся):

1. Перейти в директорию в зависимости от ОС:

   - Windows: `C:\Users\**Your username**\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
     Data\Default\User StyleSheets\`
   - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/`
   - Linux: `~/.config/chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/`
2. Заменить файл `Custom.css` своим.

---

Ресурсы:

- [chromium issue 318566:  User Stylesheets removal breaks all DevTools themes](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318566)
- [Skinning the Chrome Developer Tools Revisited - 11+ themes now available](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/UZF34wPJXsL)
- [Theming Chrome Dev Tools](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/05/theming-chrome-dev-tools)

*К сожалению у меня Chrome на английском, буду признателен правке специфических для Chrome фраз в ответе на русский, если в этом есть необходимость.*

Comment: Судя по лайкам об это знали все кроме меня. Но для меня это такое радостное событие, что я не могу Вас не поблагодарить - спасибо!

Comment: Зачем же вы ответ про субмодули удалили? В любом случае, спасибо за ссылку на Git community book, я ее раньше не встречал.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: предлагайте, я приму.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: кстати, заходите в чат по гиту: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so